# How to convert an IP binary address into a decimal in C#?

Tags: c#, binary, ip, decimal

I'm looking for a function that will convert "10011101.11001001.01001100.00000000" to "157.201.76.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ip = string.Join(".",
    "10011101.11001001.01001100.00000000"
    .Split('.')
    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x, 2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
);
```